# convert bytes array into image

Tags: iphone, image, uiimage, bytestowrite

I am recieving array of bytes from JSON webservice and it is a jpg image. i want to convert this byte array into image. on server side these bytes are correct and can be converted into image. But in Xcod i am unable to convert it into image. I have tried following Links but unable to convert bytes into image

[How to get UIImage from Byte...at IPhone code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372809/how-to-get-uiimage-from-byte-at-iphone-code)

[Encode Byte array to JPEG image in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325084/encode-byte-array-to-jpeg-image-in-objective-c)

[Byte Array to UIImage Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660482/byte-array-to-uiimage-objective-c)

Comment: You're unable to?  Why not?  Does XCode refuse to boot up, or the image is too small to satisfy you?  Give us some details and tell us where you got stuck.

Comment: if i use this code NSData *data = [tempDict valueForKey:@"Image"]; [image writeToFile:documentDirectoryPath atomically:YES]; It is saving image in document directory. but when i try to open it, get the following message "The file temp.jpg could not be opened"

Comment: How is your image encoded in the JSON? Base64?

Comment: @Cyrille: No it is not converted in base64. it is an array

Comment: similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660482/byte-array-to-uiimage-objective-c/6660543#6660543

Comment: @Maulik: I have already searched on it. check the third link. it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the bytes in NSData and use the NSData to get the image in an UIImage object.
Use initWithData method.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:pictureData];
```

assuming pictureData is of type `NSData`.

In order to convert your byte array to NSData you pass the pointer to the char array accordingly:

```
NSData *pictureData = [NSData dataWithBytes:pointer];
```